# Public Token Exchange Failure

Tags: plaid

During the onSuccess callback in the Link setup, I send a POST request to my server /exchangePublicToken but I receive an error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) - https://localhost:8080/exchangePublicToken,

which returns out my own error message in web inspector.

In my console, I get the error_message: 'the following required fields are missing: public_token'

Can't tell whether the issue is data handling my code or I'm not even receiving the public token.

For reference, here's my code:

Client

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('openPlaidLink').addEventListener('click', async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch('/getLinkToken')
          const data = await response.json()
          const linkToken = data.linkToken
          const config = {
            token: linkToken,
            onSuccess: async (public_token, metadata) => {
              await fetch("/exchangePublicToken", {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  public_token: public_token,
                  accounts: metadata.accounts,
                  institution: metadata.institution,
                  link_session_id: metadata.link_session_id
                })
              })
            },
            onExit: (error, metadata) => {
              console.log('Exit:', error, metadata)
            }
          };
          const handler = Plaid.create(config)
          handler.open()
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error')
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Server

```
app.post('/exchangePublicToken', async (req, res) => {
  const request = {
    public_token: req.body.public_token
  };
  console.log('Received public token:', req.body.public_token);
  try {
    const response = await plaidClient.itemPublicTokenExchange(request);
    console.log('Plaid API response:', response.data);
    const accessToken = response.data.access_token;
    const itemId = response.data.item_id;
    console.log('Access token:', accessToken);
    console.log('Item ID:', itemId);
    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error exchanging public token:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Error exchanging public token' });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the line here:

`const linkToken = data.linkToken`

The Plaid Server-side API uses snake_case, rather than camelCase, so this should be `data.link_token`.

Comment: That didn't work but I did find where my problem lies. It's during the onSuccess() callback and my public token exchange endpoint. I placed three console logs for error checking. My web console logged my public token, which I placed before my fetch() request in the client. So I know I am getting the public token. In my server code, my console logged "undefined" where the public_token should've been. Additionally, my catch statement executes, logging the error. Thus, I know the problem has to do with the public token not being exchanged from my client to the server. You know how to solve this?

Comment: You also need  to add  `headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json",}` to your fetch call. When I tried your code with that added, it worked for me.